# ajax only updates every other time

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an list displaying some information in a database, and when you add an item to the database I want the list to update.

```
function getList(id) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "tool/getlist.php?q=" + id);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function addItem() {

    $.post('tool/addListItem.php', $("#addItem").serialize());
    var listID = $("#addItem").serializeArray()[0].value;
    getList(listID);
}​
```

The information is add fine, the problem is that when I call the getList function from addItem(), nothing happens the first time if i call it again it updates, but then the third times nothing happens and on the forth it updates.

I ran some debugging with an alert before the update.

```
var listID = $("#addItem").serializeArray()[0].value;
alert(listID);
getList(listID);
```

If I do this it updates fine after I click ok.

I am still quite new to javascript and ajax in general, so it is possible that it is a simple mistake, but it has been driving me crazy for the past hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling post and get is call before the post has done it job, i.e. putting data in database. `You need to call the getList in success of post` so that you get the data from database. Read more about post [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

```
 $.post('tool/addListItem.php', $("#addItem").serialize()).success(function() {           
          getList(listID); 
 });
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick. So just to make sure I understand the problem, basically .success() waits for whatever function i have called i done?

Comment: Yes, A callback function that is executed if the request succeeds. More about post http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "tool/getlist.php?q=" + id,true);
```